# how to display a modification from the db?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently on a project of "to do list" with a SQL database.
Here is my problem; When I add the new tasks, it appears in the to-do list and also in the database with status 0 (to do).
When I check the checkbox and I press the 'Done' button to make it go to the state of -> done, the state in the database changes (from 0 to 1), but on the other hand does not change any space in the web page to be visible in the archives. Could anyone help me please ?
Here is a copy of my code;

in the html code on the part "New task", which makes it possible to display a new code for each new task entered;

```
<?php
    $recu = $dtb->query("SELECT*FROM taches");
    $recup = $recu->fetchAll();
    foreach($recup as $value){
    echo"<label class='tache'><input type='checkbox' name='ligne[]' value='".$value['ID']."'><p>".$value['Date1']." at ".$value['Date2']." and ".$value['Hour1']." at ".$value['Hour2']." : ".$value['Task']."</p></label><br/>";}
;?>
```

the part "Archives", does not contain a php code because I do not know what to tell it to do to display the task that has just been modified.

the code php ;

```
<?php

    try {
        $dtb = newPDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=todolist;charset=utf8', 'root', '' );
    } catch(PDOException$machin){
        echo$machin -> getMessage();
    }

    // if(isset($_POST["ajouter"])){
    if(true){
        $option = array(
            'ligne' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP | FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'addnew' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP | FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'datea' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'dateb' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'hour1' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'hour2' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'ajouter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP | FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'done' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP | FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
            'delete' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_BACKTICK | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP | FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
        );
        $result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $option);

        $add = $result["addnew"];
        $datea = $result["datea"];
        $dateb = $result["dateb"];
        $houra = $result["hour1"];
        $hourb = $result["hour2"];
        $aj = $result["ajouter"];
        $don = $result["done"];
        $del = $result["delete"];
        $line = $result["ligne"];

        if(isset($result) && !empty($result)){
            if(isset($add) && isset($aj)){
                $dtb->query('INSERTINTO taches (Date1, Date2, Hour1, Hour2, Task, Stat) VALUES ("'.$datea.'", "'.$dateb.'", "'.$houra.'", "'.$hourb.'", "'.$add.'", 0)');
            }

            if(isset($_POST['ligne']) && isset($don)){
                $dtb->exec('UPDATE taches SET Stat=1WHERE ID='.$_POST['ID'].'');
            }

            if(isset($check) && isset($del)){
                $dtb->query('DELETEFROM taches');
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you want to display sql result of 1 as 'done'?

Comment: `INSERTINTO taches` - there should be a space in there. Same for `DELETEFROM taches`

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to do - `"but on the other hand does not change any space in the web page to be visible in the archives"` is unclear. Does that mean the DOM does not get updated to reflect the changes? I don't see any javascript nor a `"done"` button - is the `done` button a simple `submit` or do you use javascript/ajax for the update?